# Layout not centered after implementing SizeConfig

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the SizeConfig method to set the height and width of my app's layout but for some reason, after implementing these functions, the layout is showing up all shifted to the left (i.e. not center). I do not see why this is happening, especially as without the SizeConfig functions the layout is centered.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
class SubscribePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Consumer<SubscriptionModel>(
        builder: (context, subscriptionModel, _) {
      if (subscriptionModel.entitlements != null) {
        final subscription = subscriptionModel.entitlements['subscription'];
        if (subscription != null) {
          final monthlySub = subscription.offerings["monthly"];
          if (monthlySub != null) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 90,
                  width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 90,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.5,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/svg/reading-student.svg'),
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40)),
                        AutoSizeText(
                          'Your pizza.',
                          style: theme.textTheme.title,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/40)),
                        AutoSizeText(
                          'Your very own pizza.',
                          style: theme.textTheme.body1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/35)),
                        PurchaseButton(product: monthlySub),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      }
```

size_config.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static double blockSizeVertical;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
    blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SizeConfig.init()` is working as expected. The reason your layout is aligned a little towards left is because you are centering your content inside a container which has a height and width equal to 90% of the screen height and width.

Explanation :-
Let's assume that the screen width is 500 and height is 1000. So after calling the `SizeConfig.init()` these are the values of the fields -

```
screenWidth = 500.0
screenHeight = 1000.0
blockSizeHorizontal = 5.0
blockSizeVertical = 10.0
```

Now when you set the size of the under mentioned container, you have the following values for width and height, 450.0 and 900.0 respectively.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 90,  // 900.0
    width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 90, // 450.0
    child: Center(
```

Then you center the rest of content inside this container, which means the content is centered according to the 450 x 900 block rather than the required 500 x 1000 (original screen) block. You can see this by changing the color of the container.

[Result of changing the color of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JivWu.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, Manas. How do i edit this so that it is center then?

Comment: Don't set the height and width of this container, it will do it for you.